# Parse JSON Array without Key in Android using Retrofit and Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, mobile

I've been working on an android app and I've been struggling with api calls/responses etc. and the problem is the api response I received and serialized/parcelized it's been changed and I couldn't find a way to serialize and parcelize.

This is the old response from api:

```
[
    {
        "msg": "No data available for this time period: 2022-11-14 11:00:00 and 2022-11-14 11:15:00"
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2022-11-14 11:15:00",
        "avg_temp": 27.59265899658203,
        "min_temp": 27.59265899658203,
        "max_temp": 27.59265899658203,
        "open_temp": 27.59265899658203,
        "close_temp": 27.59265899658203
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2022-11-14 11:30:00",
        "avg_temp": 27.59265899658203,
        "min_temp": 27.59265899658203,
        "max_temp": 27.59265899658203,
        "open_temp": 27.59265899658203,
        "close_temp": 27.59265899658203
    }
]
```

Api response change into this:

```
[
      [
          1668413700,
          -99,
          29,
          27.59,
          27.59,
          27.59,
          27.59,
          27.59
      ],
      [
          1668414600,
          -99,
          29,
          27.59,
          27.59,
          27.59,
          27.59,
          27.59
      ]
]
```

and so I've already created a data class like this:

```
@Parcelize
data class TRA(
    @SerializedName("datetime")
    val datetime: Long?,
    @SerializedName("pred")
    val pred: Float?,
    @SerializedName("sensor")
    val sensor: Int?,
    @SerializedName("average")
    val average: Float?,
    @SerializedName("min")
    val min: Float?,
    @SerializedName("max")
    val max: Float?,
    @SerializedName("open")
    val open: Float?,
    @SerializedName("close")
    val close: Float?,
    @SerializedName("msg")
    val msg: String?
):Parcelable
```

and I've Repository class like this and I've modified like this to work with new api response:

```
suspend fun uploadId(request: TextRecognitionRequest): List<TRA>? {
        return try {
            val response = api.uploadSensorId(request = request)
            val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
            val resultList = mutableListOf<TRA>()
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                val json = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i)
                val item = TemperatureResponseAggregation(
                    datetime = json.optInt(0),
                    pred = json.optDouble(1).toFloat(),
                    sensor = json.optInt(2),
                    average = json.optDouble(3).toFloat(),
                    min = json.optDouble(4).toFloat(),
                    max = json.optDouble(5).toFloat(),
                    open = json.optDouble(6).toFloat(),
                    close = json.optDouble(7).toFloat(),
                )
                resultList.add(item)
            }
            resultList

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
```

this is my MainActivityViewModel class:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CameraRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _sensorResponse = MutableLiveData<List<TRA>>()
    val sensorResponse: LiveData<List<TRA>> = _sensorResponse

    fun uploadSensorId(request: TextRecognitionRequest) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _sensorResponse.postValue(repository.uploadSensorId(request))
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using retrofit by the way like this:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCameraApi(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): CameraApi {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(CameraApi::class.java)
    }
```

Finally in my main activity I have a function that writes these response datas into the chart it goes like this:

```
private fun lineChartForDataObservation() {
        viewModel.sensorResponse.observe(this) { response ->
            response?.let { safeResponse ->
                val values = arrayListOf<Float>()
                val valuesPred = arrayListOf<Float>()
                val valuesClose = arrayListOf<Float>()
                val valuesOpen = arrayListOf<Float>()
                val valuesMax = arrayListOf<Float>()
                val valuesMin = arrayListOf<Float>()
                dates = arrayListOf()
                val sensors = arrayListOf<Int>()
                for (item in safeResponse) {
                    item.datetime?.let { dates.add(it.toString()) }
                    item.pred?.let { valuesPred.add(it)  }
                    item.average?.let { values.add(it) }
                    item.open?.let { valuesOpen.add(it) }
                    item.close?.let { valuesClose.add(it) }
                    item.min?.let { valuesMin.add(it) }
                    item.max?.let { valuesMax.add(it) }
                }
                chartModels.add(
                    AASeriesElement()
                        .name(sensors.component1().toString())
                        .data(values.toTypedArray())
                        .allowPointSelect(true)
                        .dashStyle(AAChartLineDashStyleType.Solid)
                )
                drawChart()
            } ?: run {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                startActivity(Intent(this, OpenCameraActivity::class.java))
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried and search for a solution for this but couldn't find anything useful or helpful so please I want to learn how can I do this task, and if I explained my problem badly sorry about it I'm still a newbie at this kind of things.

**SOLUTION**

I made it worked guys the problem was in my api interface I've changed to Object to Array<Array> it works that way now, thank you for suggestions and helps. I really appreciated

```
    @POST("....")
suspend fun test(
    @Header("Accept") header1: String = "....",
    @Header("User-Agent") header2: String = "....",

    @Header("Connection") header5: String= ".....",
    @Body request: .....,
) : Array<Array<Double>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and I've Repository class like this and I've modified like this to work with new api response:

```
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
```

This is not going to work with the "new api response" since your new api response is an array of arrays of floats.

You'd need something like:

```
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    val jsonArrayOfFloats = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i)
    // Parse jsonArrayOfFloats and do something with values
```

Comment: so from what i understand is, i need to modify the repository class and don't touch the other ones i mentioned right? By the way, I apologize if my question sounds bit stupid I'm still learning this kind of things

Comment: Assuming the float values in the arrays match to the previously named values, then yeah, you'd only need to change the `uploadId` function to parse the data correctly and create the `TRA` objects. Everything else should be able to remain the same.

Comment: I did some adjustments, I'm gonna edit the uploadId part of my question now, can you check that out also because I think I did something wrong and it didn't work

Comment: OK, but you're going to have to clarify what "it didn't work" means.

Comment: sorry yeah so when I apply this changes to the repository class, the lineChartForDataObservation function in main activity should show these datas on line chart but it didn't and because of that app kinda crashes

Comment: "app kinda crashes" does not clarify what "it didn't work" means. Please debug your app to determine what is making it crash. Then make it not do that.

Comment: I put some Log.e for debugging in "uploadId" and code runs the catch block and the exception message goes like this "exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 6 path $[0]"

Comment: That indicates your code is written to parse a JSON object ("Expected BEGIN_OBJECT") but the data is actually an array ("but was BEGIN_ARRAY"). Make sure the code you're writing to parse matches the input json structure.

Comment: How am I gonna do that, what do I need to change exactly to parse it, data class? repository class?

Comment: You don't need data or repository classes - the exception tells you the line that was parsed wrong. You tried `getJSONObject` when it should have been `getJSONArray`

Comment: I've updated it to getJsonArray, you can see the updated code above but it turns me the same exception still, it runs the catch block only

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.

Comment: I made it worked the problem was in my api interface I've changed to Object to Array<Array<Double>> it works that way now thanks for the help